# How to find out why Eclipse Xhtml Editor hangs

Tags: eclipse, xhtml, eclipse-neon, jboss-tools, jboss-developer-studio

I am using `Eclipse Neon.1` on `Windows 10` with `Redhat JBoss Developer Studio` to work on a `JavaEE 7` Project running on `Wildfly 10` via `jdk1.8.0_25`. 
The Project has about 20.000 lines of Java source and also about 20.000 lines of .xhtml source code.

All in all, Eclipse performs quite well. Except the Xhtml Editor. 
Once I start to edit .xhtml files, Eclipse **freezes up all 5-15 mins for about 30 sec**. This happens only while using the Xhtml Editor. Java or other Editors do not show that behavoir.

I tried the default `Html Editor` and the `JBoss Tools Html Editor`. Both show the exact same behavoir.

I searched the web and tried some solutions like switching off automaitc build, source link navigation and validators. Nothing of that changed the behavoir.

So I started to watch the Eclipse Process in JVisualVM. At times when the Editor freezes, there is full CPU load on one Core, no GC activity and plenty of Memory left. So I would say its not a general problem with Memory or the GC.

How can I find out what exactly causes these freezes? Maybe someone knows this very issue?

Comment: Did you found a solution?

Comment: Not directly. We spent a lot of time and energy to solve this issue. No success. The freeze time even increased with the lines of code in the project to a point where it was not acceptable any more. So we used this issue to convince our Boss to buy IntelliJ Idea Ultimate licenses for us. And now we are very happy.

Comment: The issue is still present with the latest Eclipse 2021-12 and any (X)HTML editor, e.g. from WWD plugin / included by default with Eclipse JEE edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using devstudio 10.2 as installed from Eclipse Marketplace (or other update site) into an existing Eclipse Neon.1 install?

If so, you could try playing with your memory settings in eclipse.ini. Or, try using the devstudio installer, which will give you different memory settings in devstudio.ini.

https://developers.redhat.com/products/devstudio/download/

If you're not already on devstudio 10.2, you could try updating to the latest.

But if it's NOT a memory problem... then you might want to report this as a bug in JIRA here:

https://issues.jboss.org/secure/CreateIssue.jspa?pid=10020&issuetype=1 using *component* = **jsp/jsf/xml/html-source-editing**

Could you also attach a sample project or .xhtml file to that JIRA, which causes the freeze, so someone can reproduce your issue?

Comment: Thank you for all the hints. Yes, I am sure that it is not a memory problem now. I will try your suggestions and see where it leads. Btw. I did some Thread dumps but these are too big to post here and they dont seem to have a clear common denominator.